# Источники лингвистических знаний

Tags: источники

Уважаемые коллеги! Давайте делиться хорошими, интересными, познавательными, спорными - разными источниками наших знаний. Какие книги по лингвистике вы читаете? Каким словаря-справочникам доверяете? Что интересного нашли в Интернет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не профессионал, как вы знаете, читаю то, что по каким-то причинам попадается под руку или имеет актуальность по какой-то сиюминутной нужде.
Верю (с оговорками) академической грамматике, Валгиной почему-то меньше, стараюсь при возможности сравнить в независимой редакции. Ожегову верю с оговорками на Шведову (большая, говорят, была огригиналка), Розеталю - аналогично, т.е. прижизненным изданиям - больше.

А *доверяю* более всего представителям старой школы. Фортунатову, Щербе, Шахматову, Бодуэну де Куртенэ, Виноградову, Зализняку... ))) Извините, кого забыл... Эти люди умеют рассуждать и объяснять, а не только менторствовать. Для меня это главное.

Отдельно про Лопатина. Я знаю негативное к нему отношение многих вполне здравомыслящих людей. Но за исключением отдельных недоразумений (а у кого их нет?) не могу бросить в него камня, особенно в плане стратегических направлений. Неудавшаяся попытка приведения орфографии в соответствие - на самом деле вещь благая и нужная. Она рано или поздно назреет и произойдет. Вот только не хотелось бы, чтобы совсем поздно.

Comment: Вполне с Вами согласна. 

Слишком уж  резвые журналисты запаниковали по поводу предстоящей "реформы языка" в начале двухтысячных, а ведь речь шла только о реформе орфографии, даже не реформе, а как правильно Вы сказали:"приведении в соответствие"

Comment: О реформе орфографии никто из причастных не говорил. Это журналюги придумали. Реформы было в русской орфографии всего две. Петровская и 1918 г., привычно и несправедливо сваливаемая на большевиков. У Орфографическая комисси Лопатина о таких кардинальных подвижках и не заикалась.

Answer (score 1):

Очень много интересных статей на портале "Слово" в разделе "Филология". Читаю сейчас некоторые статьи Николенковой - преподавателя филологического факультета МГУ. 
В своих ответах по орфографии и пунктуации мы часто ссылаемся на справочник Лопатина. Думаю,в  статье  Николенковой об этом справочнике Вы найдете интересные рассуждения  о некоторых сложных случаях. [Здесь](http://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37415.php?ELEMENT_ID=37415&PAGEN_2=2)

Comment: А что вы хотите от Николенковой?
На неё одна фамилия "Лопатин" действует как красная тряпка в руках торреро. У неё есть разумные вещи (две капли на стакан), но и они теряются за общим негативным настроем к личности.
Главный недостаток, что за критикой ничего не предлагается. Вот пример со склонениями топонимов на -ово, -ино и проч. Ну разве Лопатин виноват, что историческая норма требует склонения таких названий - и что при этом иногда возникают смешные коллизии и прочие недоразумения? Ты скажи четко и ясно "вот в таких-то случаях предлагаю не склонять" - будем разговаривать.

Comment: А почему такое отношение  именно к Лопатину?

Comment: У Николенковой? Ну я-то не вникал настолько... Лопатина вживую видел от силы два раза, Николенкову - и того меньше. Но вообше у Лопатина действительно много недоброжелателей в среде филологов... Шут его знает, почему. Неудобный он какой-то, прямой и несгибаемый. )))

А ещё знаете, может, почему? "Работы первооткрывателей всегда неуклюжи". (Приписывается Литлвуду, но сомнительно). Те, кто это понимает, относятся с пониманием, остальные - стараются поклевать.